# Issue replacing default scroll bar using jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, replace, scrollbar

I would like to replace the default scrollbar of my site ([THIS](http://nanisolutions.us/wordpress/mitzvah/) page in particular) using a jQuery plugin called [TinyScrollbar](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/). However, for some reason I'm getting the following error on the page:

```
jquery.tinyscrollbar.min.js:1Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of undefined
```

You can see this error by inspecting element in Chrome.

Might anyone have any ideas why this error is occurring? The code I am using to initialize the plugin can be seen below:

```
$('#full-height-template-container').tinyscrollbar();
```

Comment: the problem maybe in your `fadeIn`, try using fadin's `callback` func to then asign tinyscroll to the element, since the element has no offset until it is `:visible`

Comment: How would I do that? I thought since I was calling tinyScroll after fadeIn there would be no problem there. Should I just do .fadeIn(function(){ tiny scroll here } );

Comment: Doesn't document.ready run after the DOM has loaded?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is that you do not use the plugin as you're supposed to use it.

The error (in firefox firebug), using the source file of tinescrollbar, shows: `oViewport.obj[0]` is `undefined`.
If you look a few lines up in the source code you can see that the property obj of oViewport is defined as : `$('.viewport', root)`. In here root is your container. Apparently it doesn't find a html element with the class .viewport . Your page doesn't contain a html element with such a class!

If you look at tinyscrollbar's [website](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/) you can see in the 'How to' section how to build up the proper HTML for the plugin to work.

Maybe an easier (similar plugin) you can use is [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/). Does not require the HTML to be set up like tiniscrollbar's.

Comment: The best part of jScrollPane is that it works also on mobile browsers, even it's not perfect, it's better than most of plugins i've tried.

Answer (score 0):

The Tiny Scrollbar website doesn't mention that the JS library has class names hard coded in it.  You could change this by extending the library to accept the class names of the individual, required html elements.